# dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_system.dylib

Tags: boost, xcode4, shared-libraries, dylib, install-name-tool

Yet another `dyld: Library not loaded` dylib problem..

I've got a dylib (**libboost_system.dylib**) compiled from the Boost sources,
then used `install-name-tool` to prepare it for inclusion in the Frameworks folder of my app bundle like so:

```
install_name_tool -id @executable_path
    /../Frameworks/
    libboost_system.dylib libboost_system.dylib
```

Verified with `otool`:

```
$> otool -L libboost_system.dylib

/Users/TesterCodeSandbox/OgreSDK
    /BOOST_DYLIBS/libboost_system.dylib:
@executable_path/../Frameworks
    /libboost_system.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
```

Now added to the Xcode project, linked against the app and copied to the Frameworks folder.
But when checking the built app with `otool -L` it's still referring to the original (i.e. 'non-relocated') dylib:

```
OgreTest-ekeeqmnyciddaxbzyrehtcoijcki/Build
        /Products/Debug/OgreTest.app/Contents/MacOS/OgreTest:
    @executable_path/../Plugins
            /RenderSystem_GL.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 1.8.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/
            Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 15.0.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/Ogre.framework/
            Versions/1.8.0/Ogre (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 1.8.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/Cg.framework
            /Cg (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A
            /IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A
            /Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 152.0.0)
    libboost_system.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib 
            (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib 
            (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib 
            (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 227.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework
            /Versions/A/CoreFoundation 
            (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 550.43.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework
            /Versions/C/AppKit 
            (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1038.36.0)
```

And the app fails to start with the '**dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_system.dylib**' error. Any ideas?

---

**Note 1**

Now it **does** work if I also post-process my **app's** binary with `install_name_tool`, i.e.:

`install_name_tool -change libboost_system.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libboost_system.dylib TestApp`

Am I missing some Xcode option to force the compiler to change the dylib location in my app automatically as part of the build?

Surely invoking `install_name_tool` manually for the application **consuming** the dylib (i.e. one of potentially many) can just be a work-around for something I've screwed up when configuring the (application) project....